# How to update item prices in a Bricklink store?

Tags: bricklink

I have a BL store in which I have parted out a huge collection of LEGO sets. During the part out I set the item prices so that they match the average on BL. However, after a while, I noticed that due to the price changes, some of my items became significantly cheaper or more expensive than the average. Neither of them is desirable. Is there a way to update the pricing of my store including all items to match the current BL average prices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to download and install Brickstock (www.patrickbrans.com is the site it is located on AFAIK), pay for the upgrade to the full version ($20 via paypal) and then download your entire store inventory, do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> which downloads the current prices, and use the “update inventory in bricklink” option from the File menu to set the new prices.

Comment: It looks like https://brickstock.patrickbrans.com/ is the URL.

Comment: Since the Brickstock application seems to be abandoned, I use Brickstore instead, but the process is the same.